# It's a brand new age

Tags: riddle, poetry

> A brand new age of technology
>
> Six in Italian terminology
>
> Of not only French but Spanish too
>
> After that, I certainly approve
>
> Falling with sickness, in bed I wait
>
> But that was the past, so conjugate
>
> This is a useful English article
>
> An Egyptian god, undeniable
>
> Coming fourth after the sea
>
> Twelve came out on the seventeenth
>
> This archive contains some... Tape?
>
> The brand new age is taking shape

EDIT: I realized that I completely screwed up and wrote Greek instead of Italian. Whoops. I've fixed it. (This part is not a clue, I'm just correcting an error.)

---

Hint 1:

> The answer is a (well-known?) phrase.

Comment: Note to self: don't spend time on brand new puzzles. Give the author a chance to correct them first ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> Video Killed the Radio Star, by the Buggles, the first music video ever broadcast on MTV

Explanation:

A brand new age of technology

> Music videos were a new technology in 1981

Six in Italian terminology

> VI is six in Roman numerals

Of not only French but Spanish too

> From Quintec's answer, DE is "of" in French and Spanish

After that, I certainly approve

> OK = okay, I approve

Falling with sickness, in bed I wait

> ILL = sick

But that was the past, so conjugate

> To conjugate a regular English verb into past tense, add ED

This is a useful English article

> THE is a very useful article

An Egyptian god, undeniable

> RA was an Egyptian god

Coming fourth after the sea

> D is the fourth letter, comes after C

Twelve came out on the seventeenth

> Apple IOS version 12 came out on September 17th

This archive contains some... Tape?

> The TAR file, or Tape ARchive, is a type of Unix file that is one or more files archived together into a single file.

The brand new age is taking shape

> Putting it all together: VIDEO KILLED THE RADIO STAR

---

**old stuff**

More partials:

Six in Greek terminology

> Wikipedia tells me that the Greek/Ionian/Milesian numeral system used letters, including an obsolete letter digamma or wau for the numeral 6. https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma

Falling with sickness, in bed I wait

> ILL into BED yields BILLED

This archive contains some... Tape?

> The TAR file, or Tape ARchive, is a type of Unix file that is one or more files archived together into a single file.

Comment: rot13(Lbhe rkcynangvba sbe gur snyyvat-jvgu-fvpxarff pyhr zngpurf jvgu gur arkg yvar. ovyyrq vf cnfg grafr. pbawhtngvat vg vagb cerfrag grafr jbhyq erfhyg va 'ovyy' be 'ovyyf')

Comment: Good Job! I was worried you were overthinking it with the BILLED and such, but you are absolutely right!

Comment: Spent about 45 minutes on the "Greek" version of this. VI+DE would have made the whole thing a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Partials:

Six in <s>Greek</s> Italian terminology

> <s>could be the prefix hex- or hexa-</s> 6 is "sei" in Italian

Of not only French but Spanish too

> "De" is "of" in French and Spanish

This is a useful English article

> One of a, an, the, obviously, to fit in the phrase I assume

Coming fourth after the sea

> 4 letters after C is G?

Comment: You got one part correct, +1 for the effort!

Comment: @Zimonze updated the italian thing